# Python - Flask - open two webpages in default browser

Tags: python, flask

The following code is a variation on the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11126505/704972).
Two `webbrowser.open()` are requested, and they are spaced out slightly in time.

Two web pages are rendered all right, but both show the second (`Chris`) parameter.

Why is `Pat` not greeted?

```
import random, threading, webbrowser
from flask import Flask, render_template_string

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/<name>')
def index(name):
    return render_template_string('''<h3>Hello, {{ name }}!</h3>''', name=name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    names = ['Pat', 'Chris']
    port = 5000 + random.randint(0, 999)
    wait = 1.25
    for name in names:
        url = "http://127.0.0.1:{0}/{1}".format(port, name)
        threading.Timer(wait, lambda: webbrowser.open(url)).start()
        wait += 0.5
    app.run(port=port, debug=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining a callback function in a loop is the problem, it's called late binding. Both lambdas ultimately see the last value of `url`. Replace the lambda with:

```
functools.partial(webbrowser.open, url)
```

or scrap the timer and just `time.sleep(0.5)` in the loop.

Comment: I see. Thanks. For those who see this and then have trouble finding "late binding" in their books, you may have better luck looking under "closures". (I'm referring in particular to Beazley's and Lutz's. YMMV.)